# Google App Engine SSL (DNS records could not be found)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 5 app engines projects - all with different sub domains on Google App Engine. Every single one of them are just a CNAME record on Cloudflare posting to `ghs.googlehosted.com`.

There is nothing different about any of them but for some reason **1 out of 5** of them are failing to generate a SSL certificate. None of my other ones are having any issues.

[image]

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I know someone on here mentioned I could switch my DNS to a completely other registrar but that really isn't an option for me right now and I'd like to get to the bottom of this.

### How my Domains are setup:

I have my `domain.com` verified. I also have `sub-i-want.domain.com` verified. And then I select that domain on the list and add the subdomain like so:

[image]

I should note that only subdomains are active on google cloud. My `domain.com` is on another server outside of google.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @Miek unfortunately not, I just had to scrap my subdomain that couldn't get a certificate

Comment: Just a suggestion - Try to add "secure: always" in app.yaml before the domain will load the secure version by default.

Comment: The issue has to do with generate the certificates not with the redirects @Arvindh

Comment: I have found another case like yours, in the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/127231041) you can find the solution offered.